# NASM (64-bit system call)

Tags: nasm

how do i store 2 digit data using extra segment(es) and appropriate offset....i tired this way..

```
SECTION .data

offset : db 0100H

data : db 56H

SECTION .bss 

.......(initializations not required in this program)

SECTION .text

global main

main :

mov ax,1000H

mov es,ax

mov si,[offset]

mov al,[data]

mov es:[si],al

mov rdi,0

mov rax,60

syscall
```

What is wrong in this? I'm completely new in nasm programming...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix 16-bit and 64-bit x86 assembly. Don't do that. Pick one and stick with it throghout the entire program. Section 3.4.2.1 in Intel's Software Developer's Manual says _"In 64-bit mode: CS, DS, ES, SS are treated as if each segment base is 0, regardless of the value of the associated 
segment descriptor base. This creates a flat address space for code, data, and stack"_.

Comment: So can i store my 64-bit data into the extra segment.Is it allowed in flat address space? Can you please quote an example as to how cloud i accomplish it.

Comment: It makes no sense to do so since you've got a flat memory space, not a segmented one (assuming that you're building a 64-bit executable). Just use something like `mov [rsi],al`. Judging by that code, I strongly suggest that you first choose whether you want to do 16-bit or 64-bit assembly and search for (and read) some tutorials for the mode you've chosen.

Comment: Can you post an answer so that everybody can benefit from your problem ?

Comment: i used lods and stos insructions to work on es and di register

Comment: @user3555940 Post an actual answer (something well redacted, with code snippets where appropriate, and post it as an answer, not a comment, else your question will stay marked as unanswered)

Answer (score 0):

Directly accessing a certain memory address using the segent pointers only work in 16 bit real mode. In 64 bit protected mode the physical memory addresses are mapped to application visible addresses by the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). This is typically managed by the OS while user space applications are simply not allowed to temper with it. If you want to access certain physical memory you need to tell the OS map it into your memory space somehow.